# Tikz add text on other side of line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code which adds text on the left side of each line that is drawn. How do I make it so the text appears on the right side? Thanks.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node (Q1) at (1,1) {\(\mathbb{Q}\)};
        \node (Q2) at (1,3) {\(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\)};
        \node (Q3) at (1,5) {\(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\alpha)\)};
        \draw[-] (Q1) to node {basis\(\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},(\sqrt[3]{2})^2\}\)} (Q2);
        \draw[-] (Q2) to node {basis\(\{1,\alpha\}\)} (Q3);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an MWE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[right]` as an option for the node. And with the additional `=distance` you can precisely set the distance to the line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
            \node (Q1) at (1,1) {\(\mathbb{Q}\)};
            \node (Q2) at (1,3) {\(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\)};
            \node (Q3) at (1,5) {\(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\alpha)\)};
            \draw[-] (Q1) to node[right=0.2cm] {basis\(\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},(\sqrt[3]{2})^2\}\)} (Q2);
            \draw[-] (Q2) to node[right=0.2cm] {basis\(\{1,\alpha\}\)} (Q3);
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SandyG: Thanks,  I did not know that. I have updated my answer.